# Torsors over separable closure

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a smooth linear algebraic group over an arbitrary field $F$.

I am pretty sure that the following statement is true , but I cannot find any reference: any $G$-torsor has a rational point over a separable closure of $F$.

Any reference pointing to this result would be appreciated.